# Unable to activate GCP account by payment verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am trying to activate my GCP account by verifying the payment method but getting error. While 1 Rs. is getting debited from the bank account but failing to complete the process and verifying the account. Below is the attached screenshot of the error. I read somewhere "the Indian Government's payment policy is having 3 step validation and that can be the reason behind it."
[Click here to view Screen Shot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbEtV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the card you're trying to use as a payment method doesn't support automatic recurring payments, which is [required](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#debit):

> When you enter a debit card as your form of payment, Google checks
> whether your issuing bank approves subscriptions or **recurring payments**
> using that card. **If your bank does not approve, this card will not
> work for automatic recurring payments.**
>
> If you receive an error such as **Your card does not support automatic
> recurring payments** or General decline of the card, please select a
> different form of payment.